# Where does this Content-Length come from?

Tags: http

I visit the page http://furryfaust.com/waveform and it redirects to http://furyfaust.com/waveform/ with this initial response.

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /waveform/
Date: Sat, 09 Jul 2016 21:32:56 GMT
Content-Length: 45
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I found this out using chrome developer tools. I'm curious where the content-length is determined from since there is no response message body.

The page is served by a web framework called gin (https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There *is* a content. The developer-tools don't show it for some reason, but using telnet I got the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /waveform/
Date: Sat, 09 Jul 2016 21:40:38 GMT
Content-Length: 45
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<a href="/waveform/">Moved Permanently</a>.
```

Why the dev-tools don't show it? I don't know. Probably because Chrome doesn't even read the content because it'll redirect anyway.